# logging incoming traffic from google Sponsored Links clicks

Tags: logging, google-analytics, traffic, google-ads-api

a client asked me to write a script that will log visitors reaching hs site
via google adds (Sponsored Links).
the idea is to keep track of:
1.users' ip
2. what add they clicked
3. what key words they submitted in the Google search that led the them to the result page
in which  that add was displayed

i will attempt that in php.
 are there any "tools" at my disposal (objects, constants etc) that can be used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware that Google Analytics can be configured to track AdWords clicks?

- [How do I link my Google Analytics account to my AdWords account?](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55507)
- [How can I import my AdWords cost data?](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72293)
- [What is auto-tagging and how will it affect my ads?](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55596)

*Edit:*

- To display Google Analytics data in your site: [Google Analytics Developer Docs](http://code.google.com/intl/es-MX/apis/analytics/docs/). (Check the Data Export API)
- To track visitors IP address: [View Visitor IP Address in Google Analytics](http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2006/09/view_visitor_ip_address_in_google_analytics.html)

Comment: thank you  for your answer.
i have two follow-up questions regarding your post:
1. is there some sort of api through which i can get the data collected by google analytics and display it in my own site?
2. can google analytics display the client's IP?
thanx again -:)

Comment: 1. Yes: http://code.google.com/intl/es-MX/apis/analytics/docs/ 2. Not directly but possible: http://www.roirevolution.com/blog/2006/09/view_visitor_ip_address_in_google_analytics.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of other analytics services that you can use, including [Mixpanel](http://mixpanel.com), [KISSmetrics](http://kissmetrics.com), and [Heels Conversion Tracking](http://heels.synapsio.com).

By far the easiest way to just log them is to use your regular server (Apache or Ngnix) logs and manual tagging, whereby you append special parameters to your destination URL like so:
`http://stackoverflow.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=Logging%2BPaid%2BSearch&utm_content=Question%2B1&utm_campaign=StackOverflow%2BQuestions`